# Reporting services print to pdf (not export) fails?

Tags: reporting-services

When you hit the print icon in reporting services and choose a print to pdf service (such as Adobe) and error occurs and it never prints.

What could be the cause of this issue?

In our business use, we are not using the reporting services web front end to print these reports, we are using a windows app that does that from reporting services, which is failing when we print to pdf. But when we try to print to pdf from the web front end we get the same result (some error).

Comment: Can you get any error message or anything like that? Does printing to XPS work?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but as a side note. Even without the client side RSClientPrint ActiveX control installed you can use the export feature (in the toolbar next to print) and export to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is relevant for a Windows app, but I have previously had problems with printing from Report Manager because client-side printing was not enabled and/or the client did not have the RSClientPrint ActiveX control installed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155874.aspx